# This image slider starts with nothing why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slider

So Ii made an image slider for a school project and this is happening when I start up the page or when I reload it. The page only shows the arrows and the dots.
[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukNgi.png)

Here is my code:

```js
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "block";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";
}
```

```css
margin-top: -8px;
margin-left: -8px;

}
.header {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.headerimg {
  width: 2047px;
  margin-bottom: -168px;
}
.toDHL {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 81px;
}
.menu-bar {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.linkimg {
  width: 537px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: -89px;
  margin-left: 17px;
}
#toHome {
  margin-left: 50px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
#toRooster {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
#toSmoelenboek {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
#toSuccesverhaal {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.slideshow-container {
  float: left;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  margin-top: 660px;
}
.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
.Succesverhalen_Sidebar {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.Succesverhalen_Sidebar_text {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 1900px;
  margin-top: 91px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
  <script src="JavaScript/home.js"></script>
  <title>DHL Nieuws</title>
</head>
<header>
  <img src="images/HeaderDHL.png" alt="header" class="headerimg">
  <a href="https://www.logistics.dhl/nl-nl/home.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/banner-wave-3.svg" class="linkimg"></a>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</header>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="/home.html" class="menu-bar" id="toHome">Home</a>
    <a href="Rooster/rooster.html" class="menu-bar" id="toRooster">Rooster</a>
    <a href="Smoelenboek/smoelenboek.html" class="menu-bar" id="toSmoelenboek">Smoelenboek</a>
    <a href="Succesverhalen/succesverhalen.html" class="menu-bar" id="toSuccesverhaal">Succesverhalen</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Slideshow container -->
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/Sinterklaas_news.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Sinterklaas is weer in het land!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/BlackFriday_news.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Het is binnen kort Black Friday!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/kerst.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Santa Claus is coming to town!</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>

  <!-- The dots/circles -->
  <div>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="Succesverhalen_Sidebar">
    <img src="../images/Succesverhalen_Sidebar.png" style="margin-right:-279px;">
  </div>
  <div class="Succesverhalen_Sidebar_text">
    <p>.........................<br>.........................<br>.........................
      <br>.........................<br>......<a href="../Succesverhalen/succesverhalen.html">Lees verder</a></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>.........................<br>.........................<br>.........................
      <br>.........................<br>......<a href="../Succesverhalen/succesverhalen.html">Lees verder</a></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>.........................<br>.........................<br>.........................
      <br>.........................<br>......<a href="../Succesverhalen/succesverhalen.html">Lees verder</a></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>.........................<br>.........................<br>.........................
      <br>.........................<br>......<a href="../Succesverhalen/succesverhalen.html">Lees verder</a></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>.........................<br>.........................<br>.........................
      <br>.........................<br>......<a href="../Succesverhalen/succesverhalen.html">Lees verder</a></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>.........................<br>.........................<br>.........................
      <br>.........................<br>......<a href="../Succesverhalen/succesverhalen.html">Lees verder</a></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>.........................<br>.........................<br>.........................
      <br>.........................<br>......<a href="../Succesverhalen/succesverhalen.html">Lees verder</a></p>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I would like to receive an answer really fast because the deadline for the project ends in a few days. Thanks.

[image: A screenshot of my the console.]

Comment: all your slides are hidden by default, but where do you show your first slide on page load? I see `showSlides(slideIndex);` but `slideIndex` is not defined.

Comment: By pressing the arrow at the top left of the screen next to the home button, when i click this i goes to the next image. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I was talking about when the page is loaded before anybody clicks anything, how is the first slide visible?

Comment: Well thats the problem the slide is not visible at all at the first load

Comment: As i can see on row one you call `showSlides(slideIndex)` but at that point slideindex is not defined, so you are calling `showSlides(undefined)`

Comment: inside your function i noticed also that `slideIndex` is not defined, is it a global variable coming from outside the function scope???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to define slideIndex like var slideIndex=0; or =1 so it wil be `var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex); and the javascript is not loading correctly because its in the head so the put the script tag at the bottom of body`

Comment: This still doesnt work but look at the second screenshot about what the console says. I believe that thats the problem.

Comment: add this at the bottom of body <script src="JavaScript/home.js"></script>

Comment: @JoostBoth i updated the answer i hope this will solve the problem

Comment: Thx for the help this was really help full.

Answer (score 0):

There are some semantic issues in your code.

Taking for granted that that is your whole javascript code I see this problems:

```
showSlides(slideIndex); // --> Here you are calling showSlides function with slideIndex that is undefined, 
                        //     maybe you are missing something like "var slideIndex = 0" or similar

function plusSlides(n) {
   showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
   showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
   var i;
   var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
   var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
   if (n > slides.length) {
   slideIndex = 1 // --> here slideIndex is not yet declared, is it global?
                  //     if it's not the case you have to declare it on top, like after "var i;" declaration.
   }
   if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length
   }
   for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "block";
   }
   for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
   }
   slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
   dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";
}
```

fix these, give it a try and let me know

Last but not least if you want to load your javascript code inside the `head` tag you have to wrap it in a function that fires only after the DOM is fully loaded,
something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    //your code
});
```

Or eventually you can put your `script` tag immediately before the `body` closing tag

Comment: Thx this seemed to be the solution.

Comment: @Joossieπ do not forget to accept the answer :) TNX